# c++ boost::any using the value without knowing the type

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have successful saved variables without knowing their type using boost::any. But I was wandering whether it is possible to use them without actually convert them back to the original type. here is an example which may describes the problem better:

```
struct callbackInfo
{   
    boost::any pointer_to_the_object;
    boost::any pointer_to_the_function;
};


class someClass
{

    template<class T, class P>
    void add(T const func, P that)
    {
        callbackInfo tmp;
        tmp.pointer_to_the_object =that;
        tmp.pointer_to_the_function = func;
        functions->addLast(tmp);
    }

    template<class ARG>
    void trigger(SENDERTYPE sender, ARG arg)
    {
        STLinkedListIterator<callbackInfo>* it = functions->createIteator();
        if(it != nullptr)
        {
            do
            {           
                //This is the problem:
                ((*it->getData().pointer_to_the_object).*it->getData().pointer_to_the_function)(nullptr);
                it->next();
            }while(!it->EOL());
        }
    }
}
```

I think I already know that the answer  is no because the compile wont be able to check the type of the variable but anyway I ask perhaps there is a genius solution for this.

Comment: The answer is no. But isn't your problem best solved using polymorphism (just a thought, as I know very little about the actual case)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of `boost::any` as a more type-safe `void*`, it can refer to anything, but unless you know what it refers to and can convert it back correctly there's very little you can do with it.

Since what you really want to store is an object and a pointer to a member function and then invoke it, you don't need to use the totally generic `boost::any` you can create a call wrapper that binds those two things together and then use something that allows storing and invoking a function, and Boost provides exactly what you need:

```
struct callbackInfo {
    boost::function<void(void*)> func;
};

template<class T, class P>
void add(T func, P that)
{
    callbackInfo tmp = { boost::bind(func, that, _1) };
    functions->addLast(tmp);
}

// ...

it->getData().func(nullptr);
```

Comment: It seems very good. When I try to include the appropriate hpp I dont really know which one should be included to get the same result. Inside <boost\function\> I have got function1.hpp function2.hpp .... Could you tell me which one should be used?

Comment: @DarlekSupreme `#include <boost/function.hpp>`

Comment: I dont have it I only have function0.hpp. Is this my fault?

Comment: @DarlekSupreme `functionN.hpp` is the version of `boost::function` that takes N arguments. But function.hpp should be in your `boost` directory (not in `boost/function`)

Comment: Sorry for the late notice. I tried your solution. It didn1t work properly for me it gives a bunch of error. I suppose It is my fault and because it is another topic I will post a question related to this problem. But anyway I think this solution should work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, no. At least not with `boost::any`.

Note however, that you make assumptions on the types (that one is a function and the other has fields you use (not sure here, code is unclear here)), so you make use of polymorphism and class hierarchies.

Or since you already use templates, static polymorphism can be appropriate.

Or maybe replace `boost::any pointer_to_the_function;` with `boost::function<???> pointer_to_the_function;`